# How can I onfigure github account?

Tags: github, github-api

How can I Configure my GitHub account so that I can clone/commit/push etc. without entering credentials again and again. I am using Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either:

- use the [ssh url](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use#cloning-with-ssh) (and make sure you are using a public/private key not passphrase-protected, or running an ssh-agent in order to cache the passphrase)
- use a credential helper in order to cache the GitHub account password [when using https url](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use#cloning-with-https).
  See for instance "[Is there a way to skip password typing when using https:// github](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18362082/6309)".